# R Presentation - reference css template with web link

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am creating an R Presentation, but I cannot find a way to use a css template stored on a website.

This works:

```
 Title
 ========================================================
 author: Me
 date: Jan 9, 2015
 transition: none
 css: /Users/user/template.css
```

But this does not work:

```
Title
========================================================
author: Me
date: Jan 9, 2015
transition: none
css: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2364714/template.css
```

It also does not work if I put the url in quotation marks, or if I move the file to a http instead of https link.

Comment: side note : this is `~/template.css` not a relative path.

Comment: Use a path relative to your document. For instance, if your document is "/Users/user/foo.Rpres", and your CSS is "/Users/user/template.css", does just `css: template.css` work?

Comment: @user3874377 No. Just follow what Jonathan said :)

Comment: @Yihiu I cannot store the .css file locally, any way to link to a .css with a web link?

Answer (score 0):

I previously had issues with linking to https images. That could be the problem here.

This works for me. The trick was the : after ioslides_presentation. This is in the YAML part.

```
output: 
 ioslides_presentation:
   css: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/.....
```

Comment: There is no YAML metadata on R Presentations it seems. This is not an iosslides_presentation. @Sharon